# How to wrap char literal in IO monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad, do-notation

I know you're supposed to wrap up the operations you want to perform on a result in a monad rather than unwrap things from the monad.

What I can't find are any idiot-friendly examples of how to do that.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
myFunction = do
    c <- getChar
    if (c == 'q')
        then putStrLn "take action 1"
        else putStrLn "take action 2"
```

But you can't compare a char literal to an IO Char directly.

GHCi version is 8.4.4.

Error Message:

> ```
> [1 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( /Users/jamesstrieter/hask-tink/src/Lib.hs, interpreted )
>
> /Users/jamesstrieter/hask-tink/src/Lib.hs:66:18: error:
>     • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO char’ with actual type ‘Char’
>     • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘'q'’
>       In the expression: x == 'q'
>       In an equation for ‘what2do’: what2do x = x == 'q'
>     • Relevant bindings include
>         x :: IO char
>           (bound at /Users/jamesstrieter/hask-tink/src/Lib.hs:66:9)
>         what2do :: IO char -> Bool
>           (bound at /Users/jamesstrieter/hask-tink/src/Lib.hs:66:1)
>    |
> 66 | what2do x = x == 'q'
>    |                  ^^^
> Failed, no modules loaded.
> ```

Comment: What is the error message? This code looks fine.

Comment: *you can't compare a char literal to an IO Char directly* [Apparently the code isn't doing that](https://ideone.com/BRnc5e)

Comment: Added error message to question

Comment: Your error message seems to be about completely different code than what you posted. Please have code exemplifying your actual problem in your question.

Comment: That's a good point. The errant code was for a related but different issue, so I will create a separate question for that. My apologies I'm new at this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted looks perfectly correct and functional.

do-notation is a way of working with value in monad.

`c <- getChar` within the do block binds c to the char inside the `IO Char` you get with `getChar`.  You can compare `c == 'q'` just fine here because c is a plain char, not an `IO Char`.

To answer you direct question, you can use the `return` function to put a pure value into any monad, including IO, so `return 'q'` "wraps" the character literal 'q' into a monad.  This isn't what you want in this case, the code you already have is what you are looking for.

Comment: just one nitpick, `getChar` does not "return `IO Char`, it *is* `IO Char`.

Answer (score 6):

> But you can't compare a char literal to an IO Char directly.

Sure, but when you "bind" the result of the IO action it is no longer an `IO Char` but just a `Char` so that's why it works.

In more words:

```
Prelude> :t getChar
getChar :: IO Char
Prelude> c <- getChar
x
Prelude> :t c
c :: Char
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important things to understand about the `IO` monad is that the expression `m >>= f` does *not* execute the action `m`, nor does it ever call the function `f`.

Instead, it just creates a *new* `IO` action that wraps both `m` and `f`, *which*, when executed, will finally execute `m`, extract the return value, and then execute the next action calculated on the spot by calling `f` with that value.

That's it. Your entire Haskell program is nothing but a DSL for building a single IO action that gets assigned to `main`, which the Haskell *runtime* will execute for you.

So when you write

```
-- Rewritten slightly for brevity
myFunction = do
    c <- getChar
    putStrLn (if (c == 'q')
        then "take action 1"
        else "take action 2")
```

this is desugared to

```
myFunction = getChar >>= (\c -> 
                putStrLn (if (c == 'q') 
                    then "take action 1" 
                    else "take action 2")
```

and what you are actually saying is "Build an `IO` action containing `getChar` and a function of type `Char -> IO ()`, such that when this action is executed, it executes `getChar` and passes the resulting `Char` to the function to produce *another* `IO` action to be executed immediately."